# Access data from a var_dump()

Tags: php

```
object(Term)#32 (10) {
  ["term_id":protected]=> int(11589)
  ["session_id":protected]=> string(5) "11275"
  ["site_id":protected]=> int(9999999)
  ["data":protected]=> array(62) {
    ["term_id"]=> string(5) "11589"
    ["term_name"]=> string(9) "Full Year"
    ["start_date"]=> string(10) "2013-09-02"
    ["end_date"]=> string(10) "2014-06-14" 
  }
}
```

I get this data from a var_dump and I want to access "start_date". How to do this?

let's say

```
var_dump($term);
```

I did:

```
var_dump($term["start_date"]); and I get a NULL.
```

Comment: Try this: `$term->data['start_date'];`

Answer (score 4):

You should not do that. `var_dump` is a debugging function, so it's output is similar to internal representation of variable (not exact, of cause) - and it should not be used in any other cases rather than debugging.

Since your object data that you want to get is [protected](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php), you should use corresponding method to get/modify that (see your `Term` class definition)

Comment: Are you talking about getters and setters methods? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters?rq=1

Comment: No. Not exactly. OP's class could have it's own methods to work with data - and I can not predict this `Term` class structure

Answer (score 0):

You can not access the property `start_date` in that way. Your syntax would work if `$term` was an array, but not with an object.

The object needs a getter for the protected property `start_date`

Answer (score 0):

Your object `$term` does not have an index `start_date`, it is not an array. Also, the property `data` is protected, so it can only be accessed from inside of the object.

If you remove the `protected` flag from the object it will be accessible like this:

```
var_dump($term->data["start_date"]);
```

This accesses the index `start_date` in the array `data` inside of the `$term` object.

An alternative would be to add a getter function for the value to the `Term` class.